# RabbitMQ client performance

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

Folks, trying to parse a log file into RabbitMQ with pika client:

```
import pika

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('username', 'password')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(credentials=credentials,host='ec2privateip',port=5672,virtual_host='/')
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters) 
channel = connection.channel() 
channel.queue_declare(queue='blahqueue')

f = open(r'apicalls.log', 'r')

while True:
  line = f.readline()
  if not line:
    time.sleep(1)
  else:
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='',routing_key='hello',body=line)
```

For performance, I am seeing that 1 ec2 machine can send at around 300 messages/second.  This does not change from m1.small to m1.large.

For better performance, should I invest time to rewrite the above in C, or should i look elsewhere?

Tests running locally on the same RabbitMQ machine show exactly the same.

If I run the runjava.sh com.rabbitmq.examples.MulticastMain test locally, i see 10K/second performance.  This leads me to believe the Python client is slow, or I am not testing the setup properly.

Comment: Well you are sleeping. I'm not sure what the intent is for that but if you didn't sleep I bet it would be faster.

Comment: I've removed the sleep and am just running with "if line"... 

http://pastie.org/8300701

Problem persists....

Comment: @Cmag How did you solve this problem?

Comment: @LelouchLamperouge Absolutely.  the C client has MUCH better performance

Comment: @Cmag, Did you also try using Cython/CFFI/.. and simply use C as the communication interface?

Comment: like i said, C as the communication interface is the most ideal option.

Answer (score 1):

Your probably not going to see improvement with rewriting the above in C as the file system and your random `time.sleep` are the bottleneck. I'm not entirely sure on Amazon EC2 but in general when you upgrade a faster machine you don't necessarily get a faster file system IO.

Also there is a difference between publish speeds and consumption speeds. Obviously make sure its the publish speed that is the problem.

Comment: I've removed the sleep and am just running with "if line"... pastie.org/8300701 Problem persists....